# Android fragments wont show

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a piece of code where i wish to just hide the current fragment so it doesnt destroy its view and then show a new one using this :

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.hide(oldFragment);
    ft.show(newFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

The issue is that when i execute the above code, it doesnt show any UI components.

if i do `ft.replace(id,fragment);` it works but i do not want to remove the previous displayed fragment as i want to maintain the fragments and its views so i dont need to re-initialise it

Comment: you can add the fragment that will overlay it above, hiding the first, showing the second. `ft.add(R.id.invisible_frame, f); ft.addToBackStack(null); ft.commit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you previously add `newFragment` to some part of your `Activity`'s view hierarchy? If you just instantiate a `Fragment` and tell it to show, it won't know where to show (unless it's a `DialogFragment`, I guess). You need to use `add(somelayoutid,fragment,"sometag")` for each `Fragment` and then you can hide/show them as you'd like. You can also just continually use replace, rather than hide/show, if you don't need to keep your `Fragment`'s around while they're hidden.

"sometag" will be useful if you're handling rotation so you can retrieve a reference to each `Fragment` after your `Activity` is recreated, and then you can hide/show them as before.

Comment: Yea i need to keep the fragments while there are hidden basically

Comment: Got it working. missed dding the transaction.add(); this seem to have done the trick

Answer (score 1):

Was your fragment initialized before calling this?

```
if (newFragment == null) {
    // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
    ft.add(yourFragmentContainerId, newFragment,"tag");
} else {
    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
    ft.show(newFragment);
}
```